# How can I dynamically query two date ranges with Retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have an Api `URL`. I share this item with you below. I have two things. The start and end time) How do I give these two items to the URL? So what do I have to do to find these readings in my URL? I'm gonna leave a piece of my code downstairs so you can help me out more easily. Thanks.

My URL:

```
report/?pageNumber=0&sortDirection=asc&startDate={startDate}&endDate={endDate}&pageSize=100
```

and Code Part:

```
@GET("report/?pageNumber=0&sortDirection=asc&startDate={startDate}&endDate={endDate}&pageSize=100")
Call<GetSalesListResponseDTO> getBetweenDatesSalesList(@Header("X-Auth-Token") String token);
```

Comment: `&startDate={startDate}` that's not a path section

Comment: @njzk2 Yes, I know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're passing parameters into URL in **GET**, use **`@Query`** annotation instead of **`@Path`**

**Updated code:**

```
@GET("/api/v1/sales/report/?pageNumber=0&sortDirection=asc&pageSize=100")
Call<GetSalesListResponseDTO> getBetweenDatesSalesList(
            @Header("X-Auth-Token") String token,
            @Query("startDate") Long startDate, //This will append in url
            @Query("endDate") Long endDate);
```

You can also pass other parameters **pageNumber**, **sortDirection**, **pageSize** like this.

More from [here](https://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Comment: Happy to help :)